# How do I reliably find a URL to a script or other file?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have the method below to try and build a URL for a script I wish to load:

```
class WPSM_SuperMail {

    public static function scriptUrl($scriptPath) {
        return plugin_dir_url ( __FILE__ ) . '/js/' . $scriptPath;
    }
}
```

However, the `WPSM_SuperMail` class is located in the *code* sub-folder of my plugin, and this folder is a sibling of my *js* sub-folder. How can I find my plugin base folder and sub-folders of that without the damned 'code' intrusion?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?:

```
return plugins_url('/js/'. $scriptPath, '__FILE__');
```

OR

```
return plugins_url('/code/<your php file name here>', '__FILE__');
```

Try the [Codex for `plugins_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is a line i often use in plugins:

```
$dir = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__));
```

That gives you the path to the plugin file.

Snagged it from wordpress codex a while back.